# How to set a selected cell value ifrom a datagridview and use it to insert in a database?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, sql-server-2014

I have a datagridview from which I want to select the Employee Id value from the cell to insert into a table.I have two tables, Employee which has employee id(primary key),employee name and Attendance which has employee id(FK), date, expected time, time in and time status. I want to insert a record for an Employee's attendance which is done by the employee id. Hence if I select the cell (employee id), I would be inserting for that particular Employee.

Here is my code to set the values:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Attendance att = new Attendance();
        int id;

        try
        {
            att.SetEmployeeId(id = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentCell));
            att.SetWorkDate(work_date_picker.Text);
            att.SetExpectedTime(expected_time_picker.Text);
            att.SetTimeIn(time_in_picker.Text);
            Database database = new Database();
            database.OpenConnection();
            database.AddAttendancetable(att);
            database.CloseConnection();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        this.Close();
    }
```

Here is my code for the database opertation:

```
   public bool AddAttendanceToTable(Attendance rowtosave, SqlConnection conn, 
        SqlCommand cmd)
   {

        Trace.WriteLine("saving to table");
        cmd.CommandText = "Insert Into Attendance 
        (emp_id,work_date,expected_time,time_in) 
        values(@emp_id,@work_date,@expected_time,@time_in)";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emp_id", rowtosave.GetEmployeeId());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@work_date", rowtosave.GetWorkDate());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@expected_time", 
         rowtosave.GetExpectedTime());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time_in", rowtosave.GetTimeIn());
        try
        {
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.ExecuteReader();
            MessageBox.Show("Data Added Successfully");

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }

        return true;
    }

    void AddAttendancetable(Attendance 
    attendance)
    {
        AddAttendance addAttendance = new 
        AddAttendance();
     addAttendance.AddAttendanceToTable
   (attendance,conn, cmd);
              }
```

I was getting the error unable to cast datagridview textboxcell to type system.Iconvertible

Comment: This code doesn't even compile. Your method _AddAttendanceToTable_ requires three parameters but you give just one. Also the insert sql text is not correct if you don't prefix it with the verbatim character @

Comment: Also about your Attendance class. Have you ever heard of C# properties?

Comment: But I do have the @ character. That's not the problem I'm having tho. Insert method works fine. I've updated the question with more code regarding your parameters issue

Comment: The issue I'm having is setting the employee id

Comment: I suggest you to use the debugger and set two breakpoints to see what value is passed to your SetEmployeeId and what value is returned from your GetEmployeeId

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
    if (dataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count >0)                                         

            {
                int selectedrowindex = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;

                DataGridViewRow selectedRow = dataGridView1.Rows[selectedrowindex];

                att.SetEmployeeId(id = Convert.ToInt32(selectedRow.Cells["emp_id"].Value));
                att.SetWorkDate(work_date_picker.Text);
                att.SetExpectedTime(expected_time_picker.Text);
                att.SetTimeIn(time_in_picker.Text);
                Database database = new Database();
                database.OpenConnection();
                database.AddAttendancetable(att);
                database.CloseConnection();
            }
```